# How to start a program as administrator through a pinned to taskbar shortcut, through one of the "recent" files

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, uac

I'll try to explain my situation:

I am a developer and use Visual Studio. I always want to run Visual Studio as administator. I have pinned a shortcut to the task bar and in its properties set it to start Visual Studio as administrator. This works fine.

When I right click on the pinned shortcut, I see a list of recent and pinned solutions. I usually open Visual Studio by clicking one of those pinned solutions.

When I click one of those recent or pinned solutions, I do not get a UAC prompt. I remember that before I would always get this (at least, I think I remember).

Is there anything I can do to make Visual Studio run as administrator when I click on those recent or pinned solutions?

Answer (score 58):

I found this page by looking for something as trivial as to set up a task bar shortcut to always run **the command prompt** as administrator.

Richard's answer will work with programs that are not considered to be part of Windows' install (i.e. Visual Studio here), but probably not for stuff in `C:\Windows\System32` for instance.

Luckily you can set *Run as administrator* option from the shortcut in this case.

1. Right-click the shortcut in your task bar
2. Right-click the program's name (say `Command prompt` for instance)
3. Click on `Properties`
4. Click the `Shortcut` tab
5. Click the `Advanced...` button
6. Check the `Run as administrator` check box
7. Click the `OK` button
8. Click the previous `OK` button

Comment: This is a much better answer than the one above, IMHO.

Comment: This is solves the problem way better than the accepted answer.

Comment: This should be the more accepted approach.  Cleaner, easier, and works perfectly.

Comment: This option does not work if you try to use a jump list item. If you launch it directly it does launch as administrator, try and launch using the recent items and it launches as normal. The first option does work.

Comment: This does not answer the question. If you click on one of the "pinned" solutions in the pop-up list, it will not be opened in VS "as administrator".

Comment: This doesn't work for shortcuts pinned to the taskbar button for Visual Studio. The answer of @RichardBanks works for the "direct" shortcut of VS and also pinned (solution, project) items .

Answer (score 41):

The trick is to change the compatibility settings (i.e. always run as administrator) for the executable (`devenv.exe`), not the shortcut.  After you make the change you may need to re-associate the `.sln` extension with `devenv.exe`

There's a [blog post at mo.notono.us](http://mo.notono.us/2010/06/how-to-always-run-visual-studio-as.html) explaining how this is done.

Edit: If the compatibility tab is missing on the devenv.exe then use the compatibility troubleshooter to enable it - [No compatibility tab for Devenv.exe (VS 2010 and VS 2012) on Windows 8](https://superuser.com/q/465065/155331)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this seems to be the answer I'm looking for, but I can't get it to work. I don't have the compatibility tab, but the compatibility troubleshooter solution also doesn't work. It says "Settings applied: User Account Control: Run as administrator". I click "Start the program" and it just starts. I click next and tell it to save the settings. But I still don't get the UAC prompt when I start Visual Studio through the jump list.

Answer (score 1):

Search for "Visual Studio" to locate your devenv.exe

Or, if you know where it is:

- Right click on it
- Click on properties
- Click on the "Compatibility" tab

You should see a checkbox that says "Run this program as an adminstrator" under privilege level setting

- check the checkbox
- un-pin visual studio from the taskbar.
- drag the denenv icon to the taskbar to pin it on it

Now if you click on the shortcut on the taskbar, it should run as administrator

Comment: I don't think he has to re-pin it. The compatibility setting is stored globally for devenv.exe in the registry.