# How to start a "Recent" shortcut from a pinned app in admin mode?

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, administrator, visual-studio

I pinned Visual Studio to the taskbar and in the Properties and I set it to run as an Administrator.  That works: when I click on a icon, it opens VS in Administrator mode.  However, when I right click on it, and select one of the "Recent" solutions, it opens Visual Studio in non-admin mode.

How can I get it to open the recent solutions as an admin.

I am aware of a similar [question](https://superuser.com/questions/405643/how-to-start-a-program-as-administrator-through-a-pinned-to-taskbar-shortcut-th), but the solution involves setting the exe for Visual Studio to be run as an admin.  This means that Visual Studio will always run as admin.  I do not want that.  I only want it to run as admin from the pinned shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

Create the shortcut, right click it, properties and under the advanced button check the box 'Run as Administrator' OK, OK.