# How can get "Run as administrator" to work from task bar?

Tags: windows-10, administrator

For some reason, "Run as administrator" is not working for me from the task bar, it just fails to launch silently, for example, if I right-click PowerShell and click Run as Administrator, or if I Ctrl-Shift click anything - nothing happens at all, no exceptions, just silence

I see others who reported the issue were advised that it might be due to their virus checker, but I completely disabled my virus checker, and no luck.

In fact I am able to launch it via `powershell -command "start-process powershell -verb runas")`, so I think we can rule out the virus checker.

Is there any way for me to launch programs with elevated privileges from the task bar as they are intended?

[image]

Comment: Here is a similar thread talking about [How to start a program as administrator through a pinned to taskbar shortcut, through one of the “recent” files](https://superuser.com/questions/405643/how-to-start-a-program-as-administrator-through-a-pinned-to-taskbar-shortcut-th), please kindly check if it was helpful to you.

Answer (score 2):

Right-click on an icon pinned to the taskbar doesn't give an option for
"Run as administrator".

To use "Run as administrator", you need to hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key
while right-clicking on the icon. You will then get the usual contextual menu
which includes "Run as administrator".

Comment: PowerShell does. I added the screenshot to my posting. Other items Ctrl-Shift click should launch as administrator, but no luck

Comment: So this method works for you?

Comment: No, the only thing that works is when I launch from Power Shell as "runas"

Comment: It works for me, and for PowerShell I even get "Run as administrator" for a right-click without Shift. Why do you think that it doesn't work? What exactly is this icon that you're clicking that looks like PowerShell?

Comment: @harrymc Your method should work, but OP clearly has some arbitrary problem that causes it to not work. Your method is correct, OP just has an undefined problem that prevents this from working.

Comment: @LPChip: My suspicion is that it has something to do with the nature of the icon.

Comment: @LPChip I don't think so, if that were the case then Ctrl-Shift click should work with other icons, but it does not work at all

Comment: @VictorGrazi: Ctrl-Shift-click works for me on a simple PowerShell icon. Could you try it while booting in Safe mode? Or is your icon not simply just PowerShell?

Comment: @LPChip The issue is not just with PowerShell. I am not able to launch anything as Administrator :(

Comment: @VictorGrazi the method you use is correct, still it doesn't work. So there's an underlying problem on your end that is not standard.

Comment: Windows might be corrupted. Things to try: (1) Do it while booting in Safe mode, (2) Create another admin user account and try it when logged-in to it, (3) [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).

Answer (score 2):

An application that you have pinned to the task bar can be run as an administrator by holding <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> while clicking on it.

Holding <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> to run as administrator also works for items in the start menu or the WinX menu.

Comment: This also doesn't work for me. Not sure what more information I can provide - anything I run as admin, nothing happens. I can Ctrl+Shift click any icon and nothing at all happens